# I am trying to call a variable from a different class so I can update the variable

Tags: java, oop

I haven't asked many questions on here so sorry if I have laid this question out wrongly.

I am trying to call the variable AmountOfTickets in the main class. So I can update it with each loop of the while loop. I don't know how to properly call the variable without eclipse showing an error.

This is the class where I have created the variable AmountOfTickets which 
I am trying to update

```
public class TicketHandler {
    public int TicketCost;
    public static int AmountOfTickets;

    public TicketHandler(int TicketCost, int AmountOfTickets){
        this.TicketCost = TicketCost;
        this.AmountOfTickets = AmountOfTickets;
    }

    public TicketHandler() {
        TicketCost = 200;
        AmountOfTickets = 50;
    }

    public int getTicketCost() {
        return TicketCost;
    }

    public void setTicketCost(int ticketCost) {
        TicketCost = ticketCost;
    }

    public static int getAmountOfTickets() {
        return AmountOfTickets;
    }

    public void setAmountOfTickets(int amountOfTickets) {
        AmountOfTickets = amountOfTickets;
    }

    public void ReduceNoOfTickets(int TicketsSold) {
        this.AmountOfTickets = this.AmountOfTickets - TicketsSold;
    }
}
```

This is the main program code where I am trying to call the variable and used it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ApplicationProgram {

    static Scanner inKey = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicketHandler Red = new TicketHandler (200,50);
        TicketHandler Green = new TicketHandler (200,50);
        TicketHandler Blue = new TicketHandler (200,50);
        TicketHandler Yellow = new TicketHandler (200,50);

        boolean running = true;

        //Main menu
        while (running) {
            printMenu();
            int KeyIn = inKey.nextInt();

            //menu
            switch (KeyIn) {
                case 1:{
                    RedRoute();
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    GreenRoute();
                    break;
                }

                case 3:{
                    BlueRoute();
                    break;
                } 
                case 4:{
                    YellowRoute();
                    break;
                }

                case 5:{
                    ShowAvailableTicketsAndPrice();
                    break;
                }

                case 6:{
                    System.out.println("Do you wish to quit: type Y to confirm");
                    String quitYN = inKey.next ();
                    //System.out.println(quitYN);
                    if ((quitYN.matches("Y")) || (quitYN.matches("y"))) {
                        System.out.println("Goodbye\n\n");
                        running = false;
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    System.out.println("Not a valid option, try again.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printMenu(){
        System.out.println("Bus Tickets");
        System.out.println("---- ----");
        System.out.println("1. \tRedRoute");
        System.out.println("2. \tGreenRoute");
        System.out.println("3. \tBlueRoute");
        System.out.println("4. \tYellowRoute");
        System.out.println("5. \tShowAvailableTicketsAndPrice");
        System.out.println("6. \tQuit");
    }

    public static void RedRoute(){
        Scanner Red = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        int count = 200;
        while (count <= 200) {
            System.out.println("Insert £" + count);
            int KeyIn = Red.nextInt();
            count = count - KeyIn;

            if (count == 0){
                System.out.println("Enjoy");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void GreenRoute(){

        Scanner Red = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        int count = 200;
        while (count <= 200){
            System.out.println("Insert £" + count);
            int KeyIn = Red.nextInt();
            count = count - KeyIn;

            if (count == 0){
                System.out.println("Enjoy");
                break;
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void BlueRoute(){

        Scanner Red = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        int moneyin = 200;
        while (moneyin <= 200){
            System.out.println("Insert £" + moneyin);
            int KeyIn = Red.nextInt();
            moneyin = moneyin - KeyIn;

            if (moneyin == 0){
                System.out.println("Enjoy");
                AmountOfTickets = get.AmountOfTickets - 1
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void YellowRoute(){

        Scanner Red = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        int count = 200;
        while (count <= 200) {
            System.out.println("Insert £" + count);
            int KeyIn = Red.nextInt();
            count = count - KeyIn;

            if (count == 0){
                System.out.println("Enjoy");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ShowAvailableTicketsAndPrice(){
        System.out.println("Routes available:");
        System.out.println("\tRed route, Tickets left: "+  "Price: ");
        System.out.println("\tBlue route, Tickets left: " + "Price: ");
        System.out.println("\tGreen route, Tickets left: " + "Price: ");
        System.out.println("\tYellow route, Tickets left: " + "Price: ");
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I dont see a question

Comment: Are you talking about : `AmountOfTickets = get.AmountOfTickets - 1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to call the variable AmountOfTickets in the main class. So I can update it with each loop of the while loop. I don't know how to properly call the variable without eclipse showing an error

Comment: Yea TheBakker I am

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Use the getters & setters like :`Blue.setAmountOfTickets(Blue.getAmountOfTickets() -1)` . If that's what you were looking for ?

Comment: I think that sounds like what I need I just get error from that also, I think I should watch some videos on how to call variables in java OOP to learn more about it.

Comment: You can't call variables, only methods and constructors. Please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Tried using interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your var called AmountOfTickets is static, it means one copy will live to all objects, also your method getAmountOfTickets.

you have a problem here

```
            AmountOfTickets = get.AmountOfTickets - 1
```

you must call the variable using the ClassName.YourVar like this:

```
            TicketHandler.AmountOfTickets = TicketHandler.getAmountOfTickets() - 1;
```

also your method.

Also you could import a static like this:

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

    import static huh.TicketHandler.*;
```

so you can use:

```
            AmountOfTickets = getAmountOfTickets() - 1;
```

"You could think in create an object and call the var like this"

public static void BlueRoute(){

```
    Scanner Red = new Scanner(System.in);
    TicketHandler objectOne = new TicketHandler(); //HERE I CREATED AN OBJECT
    System.out.println();
    int moneyin = 200;
    while (moneyin <= 200)
    {
        System.out.println("Insert £" + moneyin);
        int KeyIn = Red.nextInt();
        moneyin = moneyin - KeyIn;

        if (moneyin == 0){
            System.out.println("Enjoy");

            objectOne.AmountOfTickets = objectOne.getAmountOfTickets() - 1; //HERE I USED IT

            break;
    }
```

But as this is static it will replace objectOne to

```
            TicketHandler.AmountOfTickets = TicketHandler.getAmountOfTickets() - 1; //HERE I USED IT
```

So, in my humble opinion you can or use an import static (so you avoid to write the same class name before your static), or put the name of your class first then the name and method.

Using an import static could be bad if there is another class with the same name or method as yours and you imported, because compiler could say, hey which one am I suppose to use?

So, I'd rather use fullnameClass.varOrMethod

hope it helps

btw using this: TicketHandler.AmountOfTickets  and this: TicketHandler.getAmountOfTickets() are avable to be used in all  ApplicationProgra's class code as i said because it is static, and because you difined them public

```
 public static int AmountOfTickets;
   public static int getAmountOfTickets() {

        return AmountOfTickets;
    }
```

=) i guess that was what you asked for. c-ya

Comment: Thank you so so much this helped me fix the problem and also learn a lot. :)

Comment: Glad to read this =9